# How to two-way bind object to combo Box in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a windows application project with a list of objects and combobox. How is it possible to two way bind this object to combo box. In two way I mean that when I add some element in list, combobox datasource should change automatically.

Comment: Is this WPF? Do you have some code?

Comment: No, not WPF.. just Windows Forms type of Application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>` won't do the job, you want `BindingList<T>`.

Comment: I remember scratching my head vigorously over that one when I started with .net as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an ObservableCollection as ListItems source. Then, add the new items to this Collection and it should update the List and the original DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with zapico - have a little look into observable collections.
Although, you could always just use an event handler such as selected item index changed!? I'm not sure on the correct name for the event handlers for a combo box on winforms as I'm studying ASP at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If your windows application is using "Windows Forms" the combobox has a **DataSource** property that you can use to bind to a source of data and a **DisplayMember** property that you can use to display a field in your textbox. An example of that can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex.aspx

If your windows application is using WPF then the ComboBox has an **ItemsSource** property and a **SelectedItem** property that you can use for binding. Here is an in depth look at how to approach it in WPF:

http://www.garvander.com/wpf/

Comment: It's Windows forms and I did exactly what is written here, but no luck.. I added List<Object> to combobox.DataSource.. But after I added an object in List, combobox didn't change, even on Combobox_DatasourceChange I wrote combobox.refresh(); still no luck.

Comment: You can try the ObservableCollection with the DataSource property in your combobox.